# How to add editable text and images to threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs

So i'm trying to add new images and text as texture of 3d object using fabric js to my 3d configurator im using this code as codebase https://github.com/devramkumardnagarajan/3d-Tshirt-design and this code for the fabric js https://codepen.io/ricardcreagia/pen/EdEGod, here's what i did

`var texture = new THREE.Texture(document.getElementById("canvas"));`

here's how i load the svg

```
function set_materials(response) {

    var baseSvg = document.getElementById("svgContainer").querySelector("svg");
    var baseSvgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(baseSvg);

    $('#svgPathContainer').empty();
    $('#svgTextContainer').empty();
    $('#svgPathContainer').append(baseSvgData).html();
    $('#svgTextContainer').append(baseSvgData).html();
    var texts = $('#svgPathContainer text');
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        $(texts[i]).remove();
    }
    var paths = $('#svgTextContainer path');
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        $(paths[i]).remove();
    }
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgPathContainer").querySelector("svg");
    var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
    canvas.width = $(svg).width();
    canvas.height = $(svg).height();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var material;
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))));

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var oImg = document.createElement("img");
        oImg.width = "100px";
        oImg.height = "100px";
        oImg.setAttribute("src", 'assets/' + gender + '/cat' + category + '/texture.png');
        oImg.onload = function () {
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
            ctx.scale(0.3, 0.3);
            var pattern = ctx.createPattern(oImg, 'repeat');
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width * 3.33, canvas.height * 3.33);
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            ctx.scale(3.33, 3.33);
            var svgText = document.getElementById("svgTextContainer").querySelector("svg");
            var svgTextData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgText);
            var imgT = document.createElement("img");
            imgT.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgTextData))));
            imgT.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(imgT, 0, 0);
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
                map = texture;
                textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: map });
                load_materials();
                load_styles();
                response(true);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

i map the `texture` to `textureMaterial` and here's what i got

[image]

it doesn't map the UV properly, anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
img.setAttribute("src", ... )
```

...must follow

```
img.onload = function() {...}
```

...so that the resource/event maintain proper sequential order. You can not rely on hoisting. Maybe undefined will have a 'center' per Fabric, however that specific code is not present(?).

Comment: actually,i'm trying other way, im updating the post

Comment: hope u can help me

Comment: There's nothing to say spherical uv wrap is "wrong", because there is no indication of what's "right". The Fabric.js ui has no innate indication of pocket, back, sleeve, etc., other than the dubious ZONE layers. So do you envision front and back? In any case, just use Fabric.js to reduce and reposition the logo and drag it around. Spherical is probably simplest from a preflight perspective. Send the screen-printer the mock which they may touch up anyway.

Comment: ok got it, but is there a way so that fabricjs canvas is only wrap to certain area? or in this case just for 1 ZONE layer?

Comment: The use of Fabric.js is to compose a texture. The use of Three.js is to apply texture to geometry. Since spherical uv provides complete coverage, that is ideal. Unless the model's file includes custom uv's. Or maybe, despite whether any included uv's are accurately imported, did you modify geometry since? An indeterminate, specific user flow may need buttons to perform your functions. For example, you can make a button which fits the Fabric.js texture to the pocket, but what if they want bleed? Again, spherical would be easier. If this is for merchandise, does one specific template exist? Two?